# How to verify if the jars were registered in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

I am using Register command in Pig Grunt to register jars from local directory. 
Is there any command to verify that my jar was registered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No such command, but you will see an error if register failed.